# ANTLR4 left recursion problems

Tags: c#, antlr4

I've written a grammar for ANTLR v4 with a C# target that uses some left-recursive parse rules, and each time I try to parse some sample code that should use these rules, the parse engine picks the wrong rule.

The parse rules:

```
expr
    : expr COR term
    | expr CAND term
    | term
    ;
```

The code I'm trying to parse:

```
...
print("Testing Program p00csx\n");
...
```

The visitor using the information from the parse engine:

```
public override Int32 VisitExpr(CSXParser.ExprContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) return 0;
        switch (context.altNum)
        {
            case 1: //expr COR term
                VisitExpr(context.expr());
                Console.Write(context.COR());
                VisitTerm(context.term());
                break;
            case 2: //expr CAND term
                VisitExpr(context.expr());
                Console.Write(context.CAND());
                VisitTerm(context.term());
                break;
            case 3: //term
                VisitTerm(context.term());
                break;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

In this example, the string literal inside the call to print() should resolve to an 'expr', which resolves to a 'term', etc, etc, until we have a 'stringLit'. This is case 3 in the example above. Instead, however, the parser is picking case 1, even thought there is no COR ('||') in the text of the program.

The ANTLR site says that v4 can handle left-recursive expressions such as these, which leads me to believe I must be doing something wrong. I am new to ANTLR, and maybe the problem is something simple that I've overlooked. Any help would be much appreciated; I've been reading the documentation and running the debugger for a few days now off and on trying to figure this out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using the `ParserRuleContext.altNum` field for the following reasons.

- It's never initialized for left-recursive rules, so it's unreliable.
- It's a huge waste of memory and I'm hoping to remove it.
- I haven't performed any tests to verify its accuracy or usability in any other scenario.

Instead, try either one of the following:

1. Test for the alternative by first checking if `context.expr()` returns null. If so, then you have a `term`. If `expr()` returns non-null, then you can check which of `context.COR()` or `context.CAND()` returns non-null to determine the actual operator that was used.
2. Label your outermost alternatives, like this

   ```
   expr
       : expr COR term  # orExpr
       | expr CAND term # andExpr
       | term           # termExpr
       ;
   ```

Comment: It's interesting that you approach it from that angle. I had actually started writing my visitor that way, but the code was getting pretty messy with all of the "check this, then check that" logic, which is when I found `ParserRuleContext.altNum`. Is there a way to just get the number of the parse rule being acted on without using `ParserRuleContext.altNum`?

Comment: That's why I gave you two separate options for resolving it. :) The second option will leave you with 3 separate methods `VisitOrExpr`, `VisitAndExpr`, and `VisitTermExpr`. `VisitExpr` will still exist in the interface but will not be called by the default visitor.

Comment: Haha, sorry, didn't see the second one. I haven't used labels before, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you remove left recursion at all:

```
expr
scope
{
    LogicOperator op;
}
        : expr ((COR {expr.op = LogicOperator.Or;} | CAND {expr.op = LogicOperator.And;}) exp)*
        | term
        ;
```

p.s.
my [ANTLR3 grammar](https://bitbucket.org/dimamartovoi/actormodel/src/f5aba3cb40e72feeaf52bd8e9c2316189c997146/ActorModel.Evolution/Grammar/Evolution.g?at=default) with logic operators and priorities

Comment: The `scope{}` syntax was removed from ANTLR 4. Also, the automatic left-recursion removal in ANTLR 4 performs just as well as what you wrote here, but unlike this example it also builds parse trees with proper consideration of operator precedence and associativity.