# mutually left-recursive rules in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I don't understand how ANTLR4 being able to use direct let-recursion actually help us.
Ok, you can write a grammar that will recognize a language, alright. But you rarely stop here. Usually you want to do something with parsed tree. And having to collapse several rules in one just to get a direct left-recursion does not help here.

An example. Say I want to define + and - operators and want them to have the same priority. In GOLD I would write something like this:

```
expression
    : binaryExpression
    | unaryExpression
    ;

binaryExpression 
    : plusExpression
    | minusExpression
    ;

plusExpression
    : expression '+' unaryExpression

minusExpression
    : expression '-' unaryExpression
```

Surely in ANTLR4 I can do

```
expression
    : expression '+' unaryExpression
    | expression '-' unaryExpression
    | unaryExpression
    ;
```

But when in generated visitor I will only have methods for `expression` and `unaryExpression`. How am I supposed to know what to do when I visit `ExpressionContext`? Is it an addition or substruction?

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170528/antlr4-left-recursion-problems?rq=1).

One can "label" alternatives like this:

```
expression
    : expression '+' unaryExpression # plusExpr
    | expression '-' unaryExpression # minusExpr
    | unaryExpression                # unaryExpr
    ;
```

After doing so you will find corresponding methods generated in base visitor.